# "This" in JS Object Literal - Different meaning in event Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, events

How can I refer the the object itself in an event callback defined within an object literal in JS/jQuery please?

I have researched various answers and articles, such as this question: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) but only found myself more confused.

It makes sense that `this` should refer to the element that was clicked as we need access to it, but how then do I refer the the object containing the binding function itself?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>This</title>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <button id="test">Click Me</button>
    <script>

        $( document ).ready( function() {

            console.log(MyObj.introspect());
            MyObj.bindEvents();

        } );

        MyObj = {
            myProperty : 'a property',

            bindEvents : function(){
                $('#test').on('click', MyObj.introspect)
            },

            introspect : function(){
                console.log(this);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In addition to T.J Crowder's existing answer, the more general case to transfer `this` to sub-event handlers/callbacks where `this` changes is to make a copy up front.  eg `var self=this; $(xx).each(function() { if (this == self) ... }`  (some ppl use `var that=this;`)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you'd use `MyObj`, just like you did in `bindEvents`, since it's a singleton:

```
MyObj = {
    myProperty : 'a property',

    bindEvents : function(){
        $('#test').on('click', MyObj.introspect)
    },

    introspect : function(){
        console.log(MyObj);
        // ---------^^^^^
    }
}
```

---

Side note: Your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Be sure to *declare* your variables (with `var`, or ES2015's `let` or `const`). In your case, you can make `MyObj` entirely private since you only need it in your own code, by moving it into the `ready` callback and declaring it:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    var MyObj = {                                    // Note the `var`
        myProperty : 'a property',

        bindEvents : function(){
            $('#test').on('click', MyObj.introspect)
        },

        introspect : function(){
            console.log(MyObj);
        }
    };                                               // Also added missing ; here

    console.log(MyObj.introspect());
    MyObj.bindEvents();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still confused though. When I add these 2 new lines to `introspect` in my original version : `this.myOtherProperty = 'another property'; console.log(this.myOtherProperty);` it seems like `this` has returned to meaning the object, not the element.

Comment: @Robin - Elements are objects, you can add properties to them (though in general it's best not to). When you add a property to a DOM element it's often called an "expando property" (I'm not sure why).